ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples in LSTM time series prediction
I'm encountering a ValueError in my Python code when trying to perform time series prediction using an LSTM model. The error specifically states:
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [741, 2223]
Here's a simplified version of my code structure:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html

from datetime import datetime

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}
tab_selected_style = {
    'borderTop': '1px solid #111111',
    'borderBottom': '1px solid #111111',
    'backgroundColor': 'hotpink',
    'color': '#111111',
}
tab_style = {
    'fontWeight': 'bold',
    'backgroundColor': '#111111',
    'color': 'hotpink',
}

def download_and_process_data(stock_name):
    import yfinance
    import pandas as pd
    df = yfinance.download(stock_name, period="15y")
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df.set_axis(df['Date'], inplace=True)
    close_data = df['Close'].values
    close_data = close_data.reshape((-1,1))
    info = yfinance.Ticker(stock_name)
    return df, close_data, info

def split_data(close_data, df):
    split_percent = 80/100
    split = int(split_percent * len(close_data))
    close_train = close_data[:split]
    close_test = close_data[split:]
    date_train = df['Date'][:split]
    date_test = df['Date'][split:]
    return close_train, close_test, date_train, date_test

def scale_data(close_train, close_test):
    close_train=scaler.fit_transform(close_train)
    close_test=scaler.transform(close_test)
    return close_train, close_test

def sequence_to_supervised(look_back, close_train, close_test):
    from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
    train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(close_train, close_train, length=look_back, batch_size=20)
    test_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(close_test, close_test, length=look_back, batch_size=1)
    return train_generator, test_generator

def train_model(look_back, train_generator, epochs):
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
    from keras.optimizers import Adagrad
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(
        LSTM(10,
        activation='relu',
        input_shape=(look_back,1))
    )
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(3))
    
    opt = Adagrad(lr = 0.001)
    lstm_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
    lstm_model.fit(train_generator,epochs=epochs)
    
    return lstm_model

def plot_train_test_graph(stock, model, test_generator, close_train, close_test, date_train, date_test):
    from plotly import graph_objs as go
    prediction = model.predict(test_generator)
    # close_test = scaler.inverse_transform(close_test)
    # close_train = scaler.inverse_transform(close_train)
    # print(close_train, close_test, prediction)
    close_train = close_train.reshape((-1))
    close_test = close_test.reshape((-1))
    prediction = prediction.reshape((-1))
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = date_train,
        y = close_train,
        mode = 'lines',
        name = 'Data'
    )
    trace2 = go.Scatter(
        x = date_test,
        y = prediction,
        mode = 'lines',
        name = 'Prediction',
        line=dict(color='red')
    )
    trace3 = go.Scatter(
        x = date_test,
        y = close_test,
        mode='lines',
        name = 'Ground Truth'
    )
    layout = go.Layout(
        title = stock,
        xaxis = {'title' : "Date"},
        yaxis = {'title' : "Close"}
    )
    figure = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2, trace3], layout=layout)
    from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
    score = r2_score(close_test[:-15],prediction)
    figure.update_layout(
    paper_bgcolor=colors['background'],
    plot_bgcolor=colors["background"],
    font_color=colors['text'])
    return figure, score

def predict(num_prediction, model, close_data, look_back):
    prediction_list = close_data[-look_back:]
    for _ in range(num_prediction):
        x = prediction_list[-look_back:]
        x = x.reshape((1, look_back, 1))
        out = model.predict(x)[0][0]
        prediction_list = np.append(prediction_list, out)
    prediction_list = prediction_list[look_back-1:]
    return prediction_list

def predict_dates(num_prediction, df):
    last_date = df['Date'].values[-1]
    prediction_dates = pd.date_range(last_date, periods=num_prediction+1).tolist()
    return prediction_dates

def predicting(close_data, model, look_back, df):
    close_data = close_data.reshape((-1))
    num_prediction = 30
    forecast = predict(num_prediction, model, close_data, look_back)
    forecast_dates = predict_dates(num_prediction, df)
    return close_data, forecast, forecast_dates

def plot_future_prediction(model, test_generator, close_train, close_test, df, forecast_dates, forecast):
    from plotly import graph_objs as go
    prediction = model.predict(test_generator)
    # prediction = scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)
    # close_test = scaler.inverse_transform(close_test)
    # close_train = scaler.inverse_transform(close_train)

    close_train = close_train.reshape((-1))
    close_test = close_test.reshape((-1))
    prediction = prediction.reshape((-1))
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = df['Date'],
        y = df['Close'],
        mode = 'lines',
        name = 'Data'
    )
    trace2 = go.Scatter(
        x = forecast_dates,
        y = forecast,
        mode = 'lines',
        name = 'Prediction'
    )

    layout = go.Layout(
        title = "FUTURE PREDICTION",
        xaxis = {'title' : "Date"},
        yaxis = {'title' : "Close"}
    )
    figure = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2], layout=layout)
    figure.update_layout(
    paper_bgcolor=colors['background'],
    plot_bgcolor=colors["background"],
    font_color=colors['text'])
    return figure

'''
Main Variables : 
stock_name, df, close_data, look_back, close_train, close_test, train_generator, epochs
model, test_generator, date_train, date_test, num_predictions
'''
'''
1. download & process data
2. split the data
3. convert sequenced data to supervised data.
4. train the model
5. plot the training prediction 
6. predict future rates
'''
def return_empty_graph():
    empty = {
            "layout": {
                "xaxis": {
                    "visible": False
                    },
                "yaxis": {
                    "visible": False
                    },
                "annotations": [
                    {
                        "text": "No matching data found\nOr\nYou entered incorrect stock name...",
                        "xref": "paper",
                        "yref": "paper",
                        "showarrow": False,
                        "font": {
                            "size": 28
                        }
                    }
                    ],
                'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                "paper_bgcolor":"#111111",
                "font_color":colors["text"]
                }
            }
    return empty

def update_graph(value):
    stock = value
    df, close_data, info = download_and_process_data(stock)
    empty = return_empty_graph()

    close_train, close_test, date_train, date_test = split_data(close_data, df)
    close_train, close_test = scale_data(close_train, close_test)
    train_generator, test_generator = sequence_to_supervised(15,close_train,close_test)
    lstm_model = train_model(15,train_generator, 20)
    figure_1, r2_score = plot_train_test_graph(stock, lstm_model, test_generator, close_train, close_test, date_train, date_test)
    close_data, forecast, forecast_dates = predicting(close_data, lstm_model, 15, df)
    figure_2 = plot_future_prediction(lstm_model, test_generator, close_train, close_test, df, forecast_dates, forecast)
    r2_score = "R2 Score :s {}".format(r2_score)
    return figure_1, figure_2, r2_score, info.info['longBusinessSummary']

if __name__=='__main__':
    update_graph('AAPL')

The error occurs when calling the plot_train_test_graph function, particularly during the calculation of the R2 score. I suspect that the lengths of close_train, close_test, and prediction arrays are inconsistent at this stage, leading to the ValueError.
I've already checked the data splitting and sequence generation functions to ensure consistent lengths, but I'm still encountering this issue. Could someone please help me identify where the inconsistency is coming from and how I can resolve it?
